# What does the "Learn from this App" setting mean in "Siri & Search"?

Tags: ios, settings, siri, privacy

Most apps have a "Siri & Search" section with a setting called "Learn from this App". I have three questions regarding this setting.

1. What does this setting mean?
2. What information does iOS "learn" from these apps?
3. How does iOS collect information from these apps (is it done via specific APIs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that developers use the NSUserActivity API to report activity to Siri and other parts of iOS.

Therefore, I will consider this question answered.